# Why does "Add" exist when you can commit unversioned?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can't seem to get a clear answer as to why this is useful.

**[Official Description](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html)**

> Add files, directories, or symbolic links to your working copy and
> schedule them for addition to the repository. They will be uploaded
> and added to the repository on your next commit. If you add something
> and change your mind before committing, you can unschedule the
> addition using `svn revert`.

But versioned files will still be uploaded even when you don't add them. I have never used this feature and historically I have always been committing unversioned files.

So what is the benefit of "Adding" instead of committing unversioned files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote this:

> But versioned files will still be uploaded even when you don't add
>   them.

This is not completely true. In fact when you perform a commit using TortoiseSVN, you can see the unversioned files when the box `Show unversioned files` is checked. You can then choose which one(s) you want to commit. Doing this, TortoiseSVN also performs **automatically** an "Add" command on these files in order to be able to commit them.

So we could say it is not necessary to perform the "Add" action manually when using TortoiseSVN. But it is a choice for the user. Personnally,  I widely prefer performing the "Add" action on each new file I want to version, so that I can commit without checking the box `Show unversioned files`: indeed checking this box shows lots of files I do not want to commit and it really pollutes my vision of what should be really committed.

To conclude, I would say that:

1. A good practice is to perform manually the "Add" on each new file before committing, thus you can commit without being polluted by all unversioned files (in TortoiseSVN commit view), so you're less likely to do something wrong,
2. TortoiseSVN allows performing "Add" automatically in commit view because it is a friendly tool: it makes life easier from time to time, but you must have a good command of what it does.

Comment: In relation to pollution, i feel you, however i think it's better solved by ignoring files. While it is interesting that you can leave out unversioned files adding an extra layer of control, there is sadly no way this advice will reach my colleagues whom commits all the garbage, generated files, temporary files everything. Thus i think ignore rules are a more solid approach.

Answer (score 1):

You never commited unversioned files, that is simply impossible in SVN :)

when you hit `svn status` they would have `?` flag.

The point is, you have to specify what you want to commit. I often use this behavior to create temporary files (like diffs/patches) in working directory, and when I'm done i just type 
 `svn add the_file_i_want_to_add` 
 then commit and it is done.
 You cannot commit unversioned files (unless its some third party SVN client doing weird shit)

Comment: 3rd party as in TortoiseSVN? I've never been fond of using the command line for stuff. Most people would argue it's just a matter of preference but since using a UI is definitely easier, why would anyone bother to use the cmd? Perhaps there are some secret powers in the cmd?

Comment: But yeah i also figured that the add function was a leftover from the cmd and that TortoiseSVN would just "handle" it making it redundant. Thanks for polite response.

Comment: I wasn't aware TortoiseSVN comes from the authors of SVN. But yeah, you are right that using UI is easier. I use GUI client for GIT because it is easier to see branches etc.

Using CLI SVN gives more power when you combine it with shell scripts. Thats the main reason IMO.